# buckling harwood floors

Tags: flooring

Tongue & groove, solid hardwood flooring by Bruce. Glued down to concrete slab as suggested by Home Depot. One large area of floor now buckling, with several other hollow sounding areas. How can this be repaired?

Comment: You were given the wrong information.  I have never seen solid hardware rated for glue down installation and a look at the solid hardware at bruce's site all of them I saw were only rated for nail down.  I really, really hate to say this but it seems there is nothing that can salvage this.

Comment: Collect your facts, photographs, etc. and take them to the store manager at the store which sold you the material and fed you the bad information. You have a decent chance of getting them to at least comp you for enough replacement flooring to start over. You may be able to get more.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, which is admittedly limited, you never want to glue hardwood to cement. Most hardwood manufacturers will tell you that you shouldn't put hardwood over a cement subfloor to begin with, but if you do you want to float it on a plywood subfloor or on plywood float strips. The problem is that the wood expands and contracts at a different rate from the cement, so when it does so through the season, you end up getting buckling and separation. Your best bet for a long-term fix is going to be to pull out the entire floor, salvaging as much as possible, and put in a plywood subfloor over the cement before nailing the hardwood to the plywood.

Having said all of that, I am not a contractor or professional floor installer, and I realize this could get very expensive very quickly. Unfortunately, IMHO, you're in a bad position thanks to faulty information from Home Depot, and your only good way out is the expensive way.